# py.test : Can multiple markers be applied at the test function level?

Tags: python, pytest, markers

I have seen from [the pytest docs](http://pytest.org/latest/example/markers.html) that we can apply multiple markers at once on the Class or module level. I didn't find documentation for doing it at the test function level.  Has anybody done this before with success?

I would like to ideally do this as a list of markers as being done in the above doc for Classes, for example (quoting from the docs):

```
class TestClass:
    pytestmark = [pytest.mark.webtest, pytest.mark.slowtest]
```

So, the pytest documentation talks about using `pytestmark` to specify the markers at the class and module level. However, it doesn't talk about having something similar at the test function level. I would have to specify the markers individually on top of test functions to get them marked with each one of them. This makes the test code look a little clunky with the increasing number of markers on top of test functions.

test_example.py:

```
pytestmark = [class1, class2]

class TestFeature(TestCase):

    @pytest.mark.marker1
    @pytest.mark.marker2
    @pytest.mark.marker3
    def test_function(self):
        assert True
```

Comment: Maybe state some code with trivial test functions and try ;-) ? What is not yet clear to me, is what you refer to with a list of markers in respect to classes ... maybe also a short sample, so people can add to this in their proposals?

Comment: THanks, I have edited the question. Let me know if it makes sense now?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For functions you just repeat the decorator:

```
@pytest.mark.webtest
@pytest.mark.slowtest
def test_something(...):
    ...
```

If you want to reuse that for several tests you should remember that decorators are just functions returning decorated thing, so several decorators is just a composition:

```
def compose_decos(decos):
    def composition(func):
        for deco in reversed(decos):
            func = deco(func)
        return func
    return composition

all_marks = compose_decos(pytest.mark.webtest, pytest.mark.slowtest)

@all_marks
def test_something(...):
    ...
```

Or you can use general purpose composition such as my [funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy) library has:

```
from funcy import compose

all_marks = compose(pytest.mark.webtest, pytest.mark.slowtest)
```

Note that this way you can compose any decorators, not only pytest marks.

Comment: Just tried to use `funcy.compose`: `TypeError: got <function compose.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f39f9529b90> instead of Mark`

Comment: What is your exact code? The code from the answer works for me.

Comment: `pytestmark = compose(pytest.mark.skip, pytest.mark.django_db)`

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried this myself.  However, from a quick look at [the source](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/_pytest/mark.py#L205), I think class `MarkDecorator` is what you want.  Try:

```
mark_names=["marker1", "marker2", "marker3"]
my_marks = pytest.MarkDecorator(*mark_names)
marked_test_function = my_marks(test_function)
```

The `*mark_names` just unpacks `mark_names` into the constructor arguments of `MarkDecorator`.  [`MarkDecorator.__call__`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/_pytest/mark.py#L252) then applies the stored marks (`self.args`) to the parameter, here `test_function`, to provide a marked test function.

You can also use `def unmarked_test_function() ...` and `test_function=my_marks(unmarked_test_function)` so you don't have to change names.

**Added explanation:** I got this from `pytest.mark`, which [turns out to be](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/_pytest/mark.py#L170) a `MarkGenerator` singleton.  `MarkGenerator` creates `MarkDecorator` classes, which are then applied as decorators.  The above code simulates that process manually, stuffing multiple markers.

Comment: Deprecated: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/8040cfd9651bb8697b5efd774b315a17e4756d43/doc/en/deprecations.rst#directly-constructing-internal-classes