# Marking test_ with multiple marks at once

Tags: python, pytest

I need to mark test with a lot of marks and want to avoid 
    
    `@pytest.mark.A
    @pytest.mark.B
    @pytest.mark.C
    @pytest.mark.D
    @pytest.mark.E`

is there a way to mark a test with some kind of list or array, maybe to this affect?
    
    `my_markers = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    @pytest.mark.*my_markers`

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else, a simple custom decorator can handle this.

```
def add_marks(*args):
    def _(f):
        for mark in args:
            f = getattr(pytest.mark, mark)(f)
            # f = pytest.Mark(mark)(f) ?
        return f
    return _

@add_marks("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
def test_foo():
    ...
```

(After writing this, I see this is basically a `pytest.mark`-specific composer a là https://stackoverflow.com/a/45517876/1126841.)

Comment: Than you so much ! This worked for me